# Flutter: Save TextField value

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I am new to flutter. I want to implement a simple Form function:

1) First page: "This is the name:" $stringname

1.1) Click on 'Edit icon' --> Open Second Page

2) Second Page: "Edit name:" TextField

2.1) Use Back-Button --> Go back to First Page --> Displays new $stringname

[3) Visit Second Page again, Textfield shows last saved name]

I implemented everything(Frist Page with edit icon, second page with back button and text field), but I don't know how to save the new string value and send it to the first page.
Could someone please give me a short example how to do this?

```
TextField(
  obscureText: false,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        const Radius.circular(12.0),
      ),
    ),
    labelText: 'Name',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)
    ),    
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data back from the second page to the first page you need to be expecting to receive the data from the second page when you Navigate to it. On the second page you need to take the value from the TextField and send it back when you pop the view back to the first page, like this:

**In the first page**

*Method*

```
void goToSecondPage(){
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context){
      return SecondPage();
    }
  )).then((valueFromTextField){
    // use your valueFromTextField from the second page
  });
}
```

**Second page**

*Declaration*

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

*Widget*

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
      controller: _textEditingController,
      obscureText: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            const Radius.circular(12.0),
          ),
        ),
        labelText: 'Name',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)
        ),
      ),
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => submit(),
    ),
  ],
),
```

*Method*

```
void submit(){
  Navigator.of(context).pop(_textEditingController.text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I want to do this with multiple text fields at the same time, I just have to define a different controller for each TextField and add them in the submit() ?

Comment: @Daniel Yes. Just create a List with all of them and pass them back through the Pop. If my answer helped you, remember to mark it as correct to help other users.

Comment: In the code for the first page: Do I have to write .then((_textEditingController){}); ? You said value, but I do not know what the value will be when I haven't entered it on the second page yet. 
And will the value be saved until it changes or will it be deleted after i close the Screen/App?

Comment: On the first page you aren't sending anything on the `.then((valueFromTextField){`, that variable is the one expecting what will come from the second page. When you tap the button on the second page that does `Navigator.of(context).pop(_textEditingController.text)` that value from the textField will be passed to the first page and you can use it inside the `.then((valueFromTextField){`.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry! Now I got that. But the button where I call `.then((valueFromTextField){`  is used in the AppBar and I want to use the passed variable in the body. I tried to define a new String `String valuetitle = valueFromTextField;` and use `valuetitle`in the body, but that does not work. But I am able to print `valuetitle` in `.then((valueFromTextField){`so the passing and defining works!
How can I use the variable outside the `{}`?

Comment: I if understood correctly, then you should be able to define in the main class a variable and then make it equal to the "valueFromTextField".

Comment: Thanks! That works!
How I must define the variable, that it keeps the value even if i close the screen/app? So I think it must be saved in the phone storage.
! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: This is outside the scope of this question, but Look for a package called SharedPreferences.